# Why can't I import the Zod package in my Typescript project?

Tags: typescript, zod

I am creating a Hello World typescript project. The directory structure looks like this:

[image]

The file `helloWorld.ts` looks like this:

```
var greet: string = "Hello World";
console.log(greet);
```

When I run it with `tsc helloWorld.ts && node helloWorld.js`, it works.

Now, I want to use the [npm package Zod](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zod#installation). When I add the line `import { z } from 'zod';` at the top of `helloWorld.ts`, it fails with the following errors. Why? How to fix? % tsc helloWorld.ts && node helloWorld.js
node_modules/zod/lib/helpers/util.d.ts:18:47 - error TS2339: Property 'isInteger' does not exist on type 'NumberConstructor'.

```
18     export const isInteger: NumberConstructor["isInteger"];
                                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/zod/lib/types.d.ts:551:17 - error TS2583: Cannot find name 'Map'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the 'lib' compiler option to 'es2015' or later.

551     optionsMap: Map<Primitive, ZodDiscriminatedUnionOption<any>>;
                    ~~~

node_modules/zod/lib/types.d.ts:558:23 - error TS2583: Cannot find name 'Map'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the 'lib' compiler option to 'es2015' or later.

558     get optionsMap(): Map<Primitive, ZodDiscriminatedUnionOption<any>>;
                          ~~~

node_modules/zod/lib/types.d.ts:620:121 - error TS2583: Cannot find name 'Map'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the 'lib' compiler option to 'es2015' or later.

620 export declare class ZodMap<Key extends ZodTypeAny = ZodTypeAny, Value extends ZodTypeAny = ZodTypeAny> extends ZodType<Map<Key["_output"], Value["_output"]>, ZodMapDef<Key, Value>, Map<Key["_input"], Value["_input"]>> {
                                                                                                                            ~~~

node_modules/zod/lib/types.d.ts:620:183 - error TS2583: Cannot find name 'Map'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the 'lib' compiler option to 'es2015' or later.

620 export declare class ZodMap<Key extends ZodTypeAny = ZodTypeAny, Value extends ZodTypeAny = ZodTypeAny> extends ZodType<Map<Key["_output"], Value["_output"]>, ZodMapDef<Key, Value>, Map<Key["_input"], Value["_input"]>> {
                                                                                                                                                                                          ~~~

node_modules/zod/lib/types.d.ts:636:84 - error TS2583: Cannot find name 'Set'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the 'lib' compiler option to 'es2015' or later.

636 export declare class ZodSet<Value extends ZodTypeAny = ZodTypeAny> extends ZodType<Set<Value["_output"]>, ZodSetDef<Value>, Set<Value["_input"]>> {
                                                                                       ~~~

node_modules/zod/lib/types.d.ts:636:125 - error TS2583: Cannot find name 'Set'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the 'lib' compiler option to 'es2015' or later.

636 export declare class ZodSet<Value extends ZodTypeAny = ZodTypeAny> extends ZodType<Set<Value["_output"]>, ZodSetDef<Value>, Set<Value["_input"]>> {
                                                                                                                                ~~~


Found 7 errors in 2 files.

Errors  Files
     1  node_modules/zod/lib/helpers/util.d.ts:18
     6  node_modules/zod/lib/types.d.ts:551
```

Comment: Thanks for cleaning up my typo jcalz!

Comment: What does your `tsconfig.json` look like? You probably are configured to compile to a javascript version that does not have `Map` and `Set` available.

Comment: I don't have a `tsconfig.json` file. However when I do `tsc -v`, it says `Version 4.9.5`. What should the tsconfig,json file look like?

Comment: You should have one of those. run `tsc --init` in your project directory and one will be created for you. See the documentation on that file here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

Comment: I did `tsc --init` and my `tsconfig.json` file now exists. It looks like this: https://gist.github.com/syedsaqibali/4bff263f3d6d7a1f89f985311a976b3c. But the error persists.